# Is it possible to simulate motion/collisions in GameScene for iOS?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, game-physics, skphysicsworld

I have an idea for a game in iOS but I would need to be able to simulate a wide range of physicsWorld possibilities for the game to work.

I can probably do this manually, but I'm not sure that it would be realistic to do this in real time (I would need to perform the calculations on the fly prior to new game setups).  I'm wondering if there's anything built in for iOS.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit#2242739) contains a list of all the physics simulations built into SpriteKit. This includes pixel accurate collision detection, force fields and joints.